# Angular-Translate: Add colon / char to a translated string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I use `angular-translate` and I have for example this translation:

```
'INFO_TEXT': 'My translation'
```

I can include it into my templates in these ways:

```
<li translate='INFO_TEXT'></li>
<li>{{'INFO_TEXT' | translate}}</li>
```

So I will get as a result this:

```
<li>My translation</li>
```

But what I want is the translation followed by a colon:

```
<li>My translation:</li>
```

So how can I do this? How can I add chars to a translated string? I do not want to add the colon into the translation, because I think it should not be there and so I will be more flexible, I can use it without or with a colon.

Of course I can do sth. like this

```
<li>{{'INFO_TEXT' | translate}}:</li>
```

but I want to avoid the version with curly brackets because of performance reasons and if it is not loaded / evaluated yet you will see for a second `{{'INFO_TEXT | translate'}}`, that's not nice.

Comment: Should it should be `{{'INFO_TEXT' | translate}}` instead of `{{'INFO_TEXT | translate'}}`, notice closing qoutes? And Whats wrong with adding `:`

Comment: Oh yeah, I did it wrong with the quotes. I changed it. It is about performance and you will see ``{{'INFO_TEXT' | translate}}`` if the expression is not evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

I did this with CSS:

```css
.colon-suffix:after {
  content: ":";
}
```

```html
<li translate="INFO_TEXT" class="colon-suffix"></li>
```

As an added bonus, the colon will appear on the correct side for right-to-left languages when using the `:after` pseudo class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom filter like this:

```
app.filter('translate', function(){
  return function(text){
      return text + ':';
  }
});
```

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/p88RxsIJksqQkBiKJ7uy?p=preview)

Comment: But so I also have to use the curly brackets, so it would be easier to write this: ``{{'INFO_TEXT' | translate}}``.